# playRoutes not found after upgrade play version from 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: scala, sbt, migration, playframework-2.4

After I upgrade play framework from version 2.3 to 2.4, the build finished without errors but after accessing the SBT shell and compile the project, I got the following error:

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last project-app-server/compile:playRoutes for the full output.
[error] (project-app-server/compile:playRoutes) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.routes.compiler.static.twirl.forwardsRouter_Scope0$forwardsRouter._display_(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/reflect/Manifest;)Lplay/twirl/api/Appendable;
```

Comment: Did you also upgrade the Play plugin for sbt ?

Comment: @Thilo, yeup,  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")

Comment: Did you follow migration guide https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24

Comment: @MarioGalic, as I understood from the migration guide, I can still avoid using Injected routes, so I did not make any changes concerning routes

Comment: but the error persist, so do I need to change to injected routes?

Comment: Static router was deprecated in 2.6 and removed in 2.7, so you might as well try to migrate now: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Migration27#StaticRoutesGenerator-removed

Comment: @MarioGalic, so to do that I need to change every object into class with injected component and add to the sbt routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator, is that correct?

Comment: even I tried to use dependency injection I got the same error

Comment: I think you must have some broken dependency in your project.  Look at all the Play-related jar files and their versions. Something might still be stuck at 2.3.

Comment: @ thilo , I posted new detailed question about it, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663300/error-after-upgrade-to-play-2-4-from-play2-3

Comment: could it be the twirl dependency?

Comment: as I see from the Jar files: 
the class forwardsRouter package play.routes.compiler.static.twirl does not contain the dilsy method. could it be transfiered in another package?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the sbt plugin `sbt-pack`. Downgrading from version `0.12` to `0.8.0` and removing it from large parts of the build seems to fix the twirl compilation issue that shows up when going from Play 2.3 to Play 2.4 in one particular case. Hope this helps!